# A compile-type template predicate compiles with Clang, but not with GCC or MSVC

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, template-meta-programming

Consider the following C++ code:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<int x, int y, bool visible>
struct Point { };

template<typename T>
struct Predicate : std::false_type { };

template<typename... Types, Types... Values, template<Types...> class Head>
struct Predicate<Head<Values...>> : std::true_type { };

static_assert(Predicate<Point<1, 2, true>>::value, "assert");
```

The purpose of the `Predicate` is to recognize a template instantiation with an arbitrary template class name (bound to `Head`) that stores zero or more non-type template arguments, possibly of different types, and no other arguments (type or template). This code compiles successfully with Clang, but GCC gives an error:

> <source>:10:29: error: expansion pattern '<anonymous>' contains no
>   parameter packs
>
> `struct Predicate<Head<Values...>> : std::true_type { };
>                                ^~~`

MSVC also complains:

> <source>(10): error C2764: 'Types': template parameter not used or
>   deducible in partial specialization 'Predicate<Head<Values...>>'

Which compiler is correct and what does the C++ Standard say on this topic?

---

I noticed that using C++17, the error with GCC can be worked around this way:

```
template<auto... Values, template<auto...> class Head>
struct Predicate<Head<Values...>> : std::true_type { };
```

But this version still has the same errror:

```
template<auto... Values, template<decltype(Values)...> class Head>
struct Predicate<Head<Values...>> : std::true_type { };
```

Comment: I've had a similar problem with Visual Studio, and I managed to work around it by wrapping the equivalent to your `Predicate` in another `struct` where the `struct` has the type parameter packs and the actual `Predicate` trait has the value parameters.

Comment: `template<Types...> typename Head` - that's already invalid. What's that `typename` doing there? Did you mean `template<Types...> class Head`?

Comment: @AnT Since C++17, `typename` can be used in this context and is synonymous with `class`.

Comment: Oh, OK. Apparently starting from C++17 is is allowed. I stand corrected.

Comment: @AnT I updated the code to avoid possible confusion.

Comment: Before C++17 the template parameters were non-deducible in this context: both GCC and Clang agree on this, even if we get rid of all parameter packs and rewrite the code with just a single parameter/argument in each position. In C++17 mode both accept that "no packs" version. But with parameter packs GCC indeed refuses to compile it.

Comment: Clang template and constexpr implementation is unstable. It is probable that Clang has actually silently crashed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCC and MSVC are correct.

From [[temp.param]/19](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.param#19):

> If a *template-parameter* is a *type-parameter* with an ellipsis prior to its optional identifier or is a *parameter-declaration* that declares a pack ([dcl.fct]), then the *template-parameter* is a template parameter pack. A template parameter pack that is a *parameter-declaration* whose type contains one or more unexpanded packs is a pack expansion. Similarly, a template parameter pack that is a *type-parameter* with a *template-parameter-list* containing one or more unexpanded packs is a pack expansion. **A template parameter pack that is a pack expansion shall not expand a template parameter pack declared in the same template-parameter-list.** [ Example:
>
> ```
> template <class... Types>                       // Types is a template type parameter pack
>    class Tuple;                                 // but not a pack expansion
>
> template <class T, int... Dims>                 // Dims is a non-type template parameter pack
>    struct multi_array;                          // but not a pack expansion
>
> template <class... T>
>   struct value_holder {
>     template <T... Values> struct apply { };    // Values is a non-type template parameter pack
>   };                                            // and a pack expansion
>
> template <class... T, T... Values>              // error: Values expands template type parameter
>   struct static_array;                          // pack T within the same template parameter list
> ```
>
> — end example ]

Answer (score 0):

Seems template parameters aren't deducible in that context. 
You might want to try using function parameters, seems deduction rules are a little easier to work around with them.

Something like this, you could wrap it around a struct if you needed the output as a type:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<int x, int y, bool visible>
struct Point { };

template <typename T>
struct NoPoint { };

template <typename T>
constexpr auto Match(T &&)
{
    return false;
}

template<template < auto ... > typename Head, auto ... Values>
constexpr auto Match(Head<Values...> &&)
{
    return true;
}

static_assert(Match(Point<1, 2, true>{}), "I am a wombat.");
static_assert(Match(NoPoint<int>{}), "I am also a wombat.");
```

https://godbolt.org/g/fjofbx

Currently the above is limited to types with default constructors.
Do you have some test types available?

**EDIT:**

An improved version could be, it doesn't require types to be default constructible:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template<int x, int y, bool visible>
struct Point { };

template <typename T>
struct NoPoint { };

template <typename T>
constexpr auto Match(T) -> std::false_type;

template<template < auto ... > typename Head, auto ... Values>
constexpr auto Match(Head<Values...>) -> std::true_type;

template <typename T>
struct Predicate : decltype(Match(std::declval<T>())) {};

static_assert(Predicate<Point<1, 2, true>>::value, "I am a wombat.");
static_assert(Predicate<NoPoint<int>>::value, "I am not a wombat.");
```

https://godbolt.org/g/iru2mZ

You could also add something like this to make it more usable:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr bool HasValuePack = Predicate<T>::value;
```

**EDIT**

Just realised I should proberbly include this, the C++17 version with template variables, this is the definition:

```
//Predicate
template <typename T>
constexpr bool Predicate_v = false;
template<template < auto ... > typename Head, auto ... Values>
constexpr bool Predicate_v<Head<Values...>>   = true;
```

These the test cases

```
//Test types
template<int x, int y, bool visible>
struct Point { };
template <typename T>
struct NoPoint { };

//Test Cases
static_assert(Predicate_v<Point<1, 2, true>>, "I am a wombat.");
static_assert(Predicate_v<NoPoint<int>>, "I am not a wombat.");
```

https://godbolt.org/g/c5gyhH